# In how many ways can you arrange the digits of the number $370612655$ to get a 9 digit odd number such that both $6$s come after the $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, permutations

**For example, “527650163” is acceptable, whereas “765503261” and “715503266” are not.**

**My attempt:**

In $370612655$,

$3$, $7$, $0$, $1$, and $2$ appear once, and $6$ and $5$ appear twice.

$$\fbox{X}\fbox{X}\fbox{X}\fbox{X}\fbox{X}\fbox{X}\fbox{X}\fbox{X}\fbox{X}$$

For the last box there are $4$ options ($3$,$7$,$1$,$5$). For the first box, there are then $8$ options. Actually, $0$ cannot be placed in the first box, so there are in reality $7$ options. For the remaining $7$ boxes in the middle there are $^{7}P_7$ choices. So, there are

$$7\cdot ^{7}P_7\cdot 4$$

$$=7\cdot7!\cdot4$$

But we have not accounted for repetitions. $6$ and $5$ appear twice, so we have overcounted. Also, $6$ always has to come after $2$. We have to account for that too. $5$ appears two times, so we have to divide by $2!$, and there are $2$ $6$'s and one $2$. In total, there are $2+1=3$ if we consider that $2$ and $6$ are indistinguishable. So, we have to divide by $3!$ too. So the final answer is

$$\frac{7\cdot7!\cdot4}{2!3!}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Thank you for including your attempt.  +1.  I don't know why someone else might have downvoted.  As for your question itself... to clarify, "*6 always comes after 2*", what exactly does this mean?  Do you mean that all sixes occur somewhere to the right of the 2 but not necessarily immediately following a 2?  E.g. 370216655?  Or do you mean that the single number that immediately follows a 2 must always be a 6?  E.g. 36012655?

Comment: If you mean the first, then I agree with your answer.  If you mean the second, then I would imagine this as "*gluing the 2 and one of the 6's together*" and calling that a single character... $Z$, and arranging $0135567Z$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you. I mean the first. Please glance at the extreme top of my question immediately below the title. I included examples. I will embolden them now, as they seem to be in a blind spot.

Comment: Also, what does "all the numbers are odd" mean, especially when there even digits in this number? Do you mean odd digits in a particular place, like the last digit?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer from context and the attempt, clearly yes they mean that the last digit must be odd.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Yes, I mean that the last digit of the number will have to be odd so as to make the whole number odd. For example, 527650163 is an acceptable arrangement (as it is odd), whereas 527650136 is unacceptable (as it is even).

Comment: Based on the examples given in the beginning of the problem, I would interpret that both  6s must occur somewhere after the 2 (but not necessarily immediately after the 2). Does anyone see it differently?

Comment: I think the phrasing of the title is a little confusing. I'm planning to correct it and make things easier at the starting, and some MathJax and the likes.

Comment: @paw88789 Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @paw88789 this was clarified already with the first comments and the OP's response

Comment: Also, while writing solution verification questions, please avoid question of the form : "questions+attempt+ "am I right/is this fine?" ". Take a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35592/how-to-ask-a-good-proof-verification-question) for improving such questions. In this case, adding a source to your proof and pointing out parts of the proof that you think might be wrong are important. I have corrected some ambiguities within the question.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer what are you talking about?  I don't agree that this falls under that case.  This is a typical short-form question and we ask users to include their attempts for such questions.  The OP did exactly that, as requested.  The proof-verification you are referring to is more for if it is a long-form proof or someone else's proof that the OP is asking clarification on specific steps of.

Comment: @JMoravitz In that question, more was demanded of both proof and solution-verification type questions. Note that I have taken no moderation action on this post and do not plan to take any (other than the edits), but for me it does fall under that case. "We ask users to include their attempt" you might do that, I plan to ask for more in general.

Comment: Also, "what are you talking about"/ "clearly yes they mean" these come across as disrespectful to me. Kindly do not ping me anymore in this conversation,@JMoravitz, thank you otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: pick the odd number at the end.  You have four options, but one of those is special.  Break into cases based on which it was:

Case 1: if the odd number in the units digit position was a 5

Case 2: if the odd number in the units digit position was a 1,3 or 7

Regardless which case it was, then pick the position of the $0$.  It may not be the front.  (*I find it easier to phrase this way so we don't have to further break into cases*)

Now, arrange the remaining numbers... using your idea of treating the 2 and the 6's as indistinguishable for now.  Here is where which case we are in is relevant.  If it was that we have only a single 5 remaining, we will *not* need to divide by $2$ to account for symmetry.  It is only in the event that a 5 was not used as the units digit that we will have two indistinguishable 5's to concern ourselves with for symmetry.

Finish by clarifying that the 2 takes the first of the three positions selected for the 2 and 6's.

This gives an answer of:

$$1\cdot 7 \cdot \frac{7!}{3!} + 3\cdot 7\cdot \frac{7!}{2!3!} = 14700$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm coming up with something different:

Place the $0$, There are $7$ choices for this, since $0$ can't go in the first or last slot.

Pick $3$ of the remaining slots for $2, 6, 6$.  This can be done in ${7}\choose{3}$ ways--we can't use the last slot; and we can't use the slot where $0$ is.

Note that once the slots for $2,6,6$ have been chosen, there is only one way to place these three digits, since the $2$ must come first.

Pick two of the remaining five slots for the $5$s.  This can be done in ${5}\choose {2}$ ways.

Arrange $1, 3, 7$ in the remaining three slots. This can be done in $3!$ ways.

Total: $7\cdot {{7}\choose{3}}\cdot {{5}\choose{2}}\cdot 3!=14,700$ ways.